# Is there a GUI front-end to Apache for Mac OS X (Lion)?

Tags: macos, ui, apache

I am using the default Apache and PHP installs that are present in OS X Lion. But I would like to make some settings (like adding Virtual Hosts to Apache) using a GUI interface. Is there such a thing?

I know of OS X Server of course, and also I think MAMP Pro has this. But I would like to keep using the stock servers and not install another version if I don't have to.

Comment: FYI, installing MAMP Pro is as easy as installing any other app. It's self contained, doesn't mess with the bundled install and has the GUI you're asking for. And it's probably more up-to-date.

Comment: You should try MAMP. It's so easy to set up it's ridiculous. MAMP is free and you can upgrade to the paid MAMP Pro if you need it.

Comment: I know MAMP is simple, but as the bundled versions in Lion are pretty new, I'd like to integrate with them if I can.

Answer (score 5):

There's no *built-in* GUI, but there are third party ones. One that I know of for managing virtual hosts is called VirtualHostX: http://clickontyler.com/virtualhostx/

Comment: That looks to be exactly what I was looking for. If people know of similar programs, please add them.

Comment: perfect! just what I was after - now if only I could figure out how to make folders...

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no GUI for the built-in apache. This is how I just set mine up so I can add my own VirtualHosts more easily:

```
sudo -s
mkdir /etc/apache2/vhosts
chgrp admin /etc/apache2/vhosts
chmod g+w /etc/apache2/vhosts
cat << EOF >> /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
#
# Load user-defined vhosts
#
Include /private/etc/apache2/vhosts/*.conf
EOF
```

This adds a vhosts directory under /etc/apache2/vhosts. You just need to turn on vhosts in the master /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file, and then it will look for all .conf files in that vhosts directory. I made it so as an admin user I have privileges to save in there.

It's a little tidier than trying to put everything in one file like the example vhosts in the config file.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed a step in the direction of ease and tidiness.

Answer (score 1):

There's another GUI for built-in apache: [WebMon for Mountain Lion](http://cutedgesystems.com/software/WebMonForMountainLion/). But this one is not as simple as VirtualHostX.